# e.preventDefault() not a function NextJS/React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

The only other answer I found regarding this was one where the event was not being passed to the function. That is not the case here. I'm clearly passing the event as variable e. I have the button type as submit, so the form is being submitted with the event. Also, the handleChange function works properly with the event. I copied this format over from a Udemy course I was taking and I practically have the exact same thing. The only big difference I can think of is that the Udemy course had all of this logic in a separate component that was imported in and then rendered to the page, where as the form and form handling logic is the main component on this page.

Please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong!

**Error:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Router, { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import { Col, Row, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { createPatient } from '../../actions/patient';

const CreatePatient = ({ router }) => {

    const [ values, setValues ] = useState({
        error: '',
        formData: '',
        data: ''
    });

    const { error, formData } = values;

    useEffect(() => {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            formData: new FormData()
        })
    }, [router])

    const createPatient = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        createPatient(formData).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            }
        })
    }

    const handleChange = name => e => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        
        formData.set(name, value);

        setValues({ ...values, [name]: value, formData, error: '' });
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <section className="container pt-3">
                <form className="form" onSubmit={ createPatient }>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4 my-2">
                            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" onChange={handleChange('firstName')}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-4 my-2">
                            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" onChange={handleChange('lastName')}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-2">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default withRouter(CreatePatient);
```

Comment: You are overriding ``createPatient``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `createPatient` inside of `createPatient`, while passing a non-event. Instead of this:

```js
const createPatient = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        
    createPatient(formData).then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
        }
    })
}
```

Just change it to something more like this:

```js
const createPatient = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        
    // run your API call here, then...
    if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch this!! So the first call was in fact correct, but I recursively called it again and the 'e' was the formData the second time. I understand now (silly mistake lol)

Answer (score 0):

the `e` symbol in `createPatient`  method here is not an event, that's why you get the error. Within a submit you get the element returned, not the event. So, `e` here is your element.

markup

```
<form className="form" onSubmit={ createPatient }
```

js

```
const createPatient = (e) => {
    console.log(e); // the form div
    
    createPatient(formData).then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. How do I get the event?

Comment: NeoNexus Demortis's answer is actually right. I was using the name createPatient twice, calling the function again. The 'e' being passed actually is the event, I was just calling createPatient recurisvely in the createPatient function and the second time I was not passing the event but rather the formData. I accepted his answer.